# Java String.format() leading zeros and 1 decimal place

Tags: java, string, format

I need a string like `50` to appear as `050.0`. I am using String.format, but I can't figure out how to do leading zeros *and* a single decimal place at the same time. So far, I have tried `String.format("%3.2f", number);`, but that isn't working as I still get `50.0` rather than `050.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to control the number of mandatory digits:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#000.0");
System.out.println(df.format(50)); // 050.0
```

where

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning
0       Number      Yes         Digit
#       Number      Yes         Digit, zero shows as absent
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder class to create a string with number 0 and then append it with you number and insert the decimals at the end.

```
 int num = 50; /*Your number*/
 StringBuilder s_num = new StringBuilder("0"); 
 s_num.append(num); 
 s_num.append(".0");
 String f_num = s_num.toString();
```